# Given the coordinates of two vectors, what is the condition for when the displacement is different from distance vector?

Tags: vectors, physics

The coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of two points $C$ and $D$ are $(2,7,-2)$ and $(-4,4,-8)$. Find the distance and displacement vector from $C$ to $D$.

From a solution I found online the distance equals the displacement vector $\big(-4-2,\; 4-7,\; -8-(-2)\big)$.

Displacement is shortest distance travelled unlike distance which is total distance. In which case can we say that these two values will be different?

Comment: Displacement is a vector.  Distance is the length of the displacement vector.  You can't compare them.

Comment: If a path is given, you can measure distance along the path. But generally if a path is not specified, "distance" means shortest distance, which is along a straight line. So the distance between two points is equal to the magnitude (length) of the displacement vector. However, to say that the distance (a single number) is equal to the displacement (a vector described by three numbers) is not correct.

Comment: Displacement is a vector.  Distance is the length of the displacement vector.  You can't compare them.

Comment: Ok.@saulspatz  Thanks

Comment: @DavidK Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The displacement vector from point $ C$ to $D$ will be

$\vec r=\vec r_D-\vec r_C$

$\vec r=(-4\hat i+4\hat j -8\hat k)-(2\hat i+7\hat j -2\hat k)$

$\vec r=(-6\hat i-3\hat j -6\hat k)$

The distance between these two points is the magnitude of this displacement vector and is equal to $9$ units